# Typescript error with generic "Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type T"

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

A have a typecheck error

```js
interface IProps<T> {
    query: T;
    setQuery: (q: Partial<T>) => void;
}

const fn = <T extends { page: number }>(props: IProps<T>) => {
    props.setQuery({ page: 123 });
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAOBnAHgBUA%20ZAbwFgAoZO5ARwFdoBPALmSIG4b7k8EMAEUWUDsgAUDTujhQwwOABtiJAJTIAvGQBuWYABNe1AL40aCLCDxhkMENuTFkEAB6QQhvBWQ44AOYQnCBMALYARtDIpiSSONj4nBiJhKSaOhR89Am4eAB0giJirJLkfoHByACMAEwAzDHqJubUQA)

Can't understand why `props.setQuery({ page: 123 });` throws error ?

Comment: Argument of type '{ page: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  '{ page: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ page: number; }'. T could actually have more required properties and the compiler is complaining that the constraint could be invalidated by your object literal.

Comment: @JaredSmith But `setQuery` doesn't take `T`. It takes `Partial<T>`, and I believe it does work (in a non-generic context) to pass a supertype of `T` for `Partial<T>` because all the missing fields are made optional by `Partial` anyway. The issue is that the compiler doesn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent question which stumped me at first but I think I've got the reason.  The edge case which makes it not assignable is where `T extends { page: number }` sets a more narrow definition for `page` that `123` is not assignable to.  That would occur if `T` has a property `page` which is a number literal or a union of number literals.

```
fn<{page: 1 | 2}>({query: {page: 1}, setQuery: ({page}) => {}})
```

The type of `page` in the `setQuery` callback of the above example is `1 | 2 | undefined`.  So calling `setQuery` with `{ page: 123 }` would not be valid.

The errors that you are getting are not very helpful, it should really be the "could be instantiated with an arbitrary type" message.

In practice this sort of usage where you've manually set a generic with a restrictive type is extremely unlikely, so it's pretty safe to just assert correctness: `props.setQuery({ page: 123 } as Partial<T>);`

I'm trying to think of how we can disallow that edge case to avoid using `as`.  It seems like `props: IProps<Omit<T, 'page'> & { page: number }>` should work but I must still be missing something because that gives an error.

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/nmqdQN)